# Trying to instantiate Commercial Paper smart contract, error starting container /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am using HF 1.4.9 and VS Code 1.39.2 with the IBP extension. Docker version 19.03.13 running on MacOS Catalina. Several other people that are doing the same lab with me and have different operating system are running into exactly the same error.

This is the command: `docker exec cliMagnetoCorp peer chaincode instantiate -n papercontract -v 0.0.3 -l node -c '{"Args":["org.papernet.commercialpaper:instantiate"]}' -C mychannel -P "AND ('Org1MSP.member')"`

and the output in the MagnetoCorp terminal window is:

```
2020-10-17 18:31:35.067 UTC [chaincodeCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Retrieved channel (mychannel) orderer endpoint: orderer.example.com:7050
2020-10-17 18:31:35.076 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default escc
2020-10-17 18:31:35.076 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Post http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0.0.3: dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

In the monitor logs terminal window I get the following error:

```
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-17 18:31:35.167 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> ERRO 049 create container failed: Post http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0.0.3: dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory imageName=dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0.0.3-5f1d60e28249e81faa02102ce57e28b86443fdc9c08e350371a8b90ac690ae6e containerName=dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0.0.3
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-17 18:31:35.182 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 04a [mychannel][721d6ed1] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (98ms)
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-17 18:31:35.182 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 04b [mychannel][721d6ed1] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: Post http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0.0.3: dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory
peer0.org1.example.com|error starting container
peer0.org1.example.com|error starting container
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-10-17 18:31:35.183 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04c unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.7:40046 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=100.6563ms
   orderer.example.com|2020-10-17 18:31:35.200 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 00e Error reading from 172.19.0.7:36270: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
   orderer.example.com|2020-10-17 18:31:35.200 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00f streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.19.0.7:36270 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=120.6555ms
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I was able to solve it. With the version of Docker that now has the "Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing" enabled by default. Unclicked that, restarted my environment. I teardowned everything and recreated and was able to instantiate. This was what lead me to the solution https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-18134 https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4955